# jquery formwizard how to validate radio button only if it is enabled?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, formwizard

i have a pair of radio buttons that upon certain circumstances will be enabled or disabled.

Is there a way to have it validate the radio button only if the radio buttons have a certain class like "rb_enabled"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the class of wizard-ignore to the radio to have it ignored.

http://thecodemine.org/examples/example_16_have_the_wizard_ignore_specific_inputs_during_transition.html